# is it possible to change the content in web page dynamically based on previous page input using jsp

Tags: jsp

Using jsp is it possible to change the content in web page dynamically based on previous page input ?
Please provide me some example code also. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Let you have a previous page as **index.jsp**(or if no processing is done, then it can be index.html)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="nextPage.jsp" method="POST">
Name <input type="text" name="user_name">
<input type="submit" name="submit_form">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and at JSP side ie in **nextPage.jsp**, use the following code:

```
String str=request.getParameter("user_name");
out.println("Hello "+ str);
```

**It's just demonstration, you can use your code n logic according to your requirements.**